# How do you write a query to display price, price discount, then create a column for new price

Tags: sql

How do you write a query to display price, price discount, then create a column for new price? I'm using oracle sql.

Comment: Your question is too broad, lacking any data or description of the problem at hand and it's unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
select price, price_discount, (price - price_discount) as new_price from table
```

if you want to create a permanent column with the new price you would use alter table to create the new column

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD new_price decimal(10, 2);
```

and then

```
update table set new_price = price - price_discount
```

Comment: Still not adding the new column to the table.

Comment: Did you use the alter table statement to create the new column before trying to populate the column with an update statement? You should substitute your own table name where I use lowercase 'table' above.